# Ionic.Zip c# : Maximum folder size this tool compressed

Tags: c#

Ionic.Zip c# : 
I am using Ionic.Zip tool for Ziping and Unziping the file.

Getting this error while ziping the 7 GB Size File Which is having 13K File inside the folder.

Error: ZipFoldersCompressed or Uncompressed size, or offset exceeds the maximum value. Consider setting the UseZip64WhenSaving property on the ZipFile instance.

can anyone please tell me

1) What is Maximum folder size this tool compressed.(Maximum Folder Size it can Zip) ?

2).How many file is allowed in single folder (Number of File Count inside any Folder) ?

Please help me with answer..

thanks

Comment: What version of zip are you using?  Older zip utilities have bugs and I can't tell if the issue was with the tool that zipped or the unzipped tool.

Comment: Version=1.9.1.8

Comment: See specifcation : https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT